# Refresh TextBox text?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox

I will explain the situation:

1. My form have a listview, a textbox, and a label.
2. The Textbox is to write a directory path to add that directory to the listview.
3. With the event OnTextchanged of the textbox I check if the listview contains the textbox text before adding it, if yes then the label says "**Directory is already in the listview**" if not then the label says otherwise.
4. Now, after adding the directory path from the textbox to the listview, like I don't modified the textbox text after adding the text to the listview then the OnTextChanged event of the textbox is not processed so the label is still saying that the directory **IS NOT** inside the listview (because the OnTextchanged event is not processed).

Then to solve this little issue I refresh the text of the textbox after adding the text to the listviewx, I did it with a little snippet I've made for this:

```
Private Sub Refresh_Textbox_Text(ByVal TextBox As TextBox)
    Dim TempText As String = TextBox.Text
    TextBox.Clear()
    TextBox.Text = TempText
End Sub
```

But I think that's a noob way to do it, I wonder if exists a native method to do refresh in the way I need the text of a textbox like seen in that snippet, I've tried with some methods as "refresh", "invalidate", etc... but none does the same.

Comment: What platform? ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, MVC...?

Comment: It is not clear to me what is your problem. Do you want to clear the label text after adding the TextBox.Text to the listbox?

Comment: Is the directory typed or pasted entirely? What triggers the add to the ListView, pressing return or a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is not a Native way to raise the `TextChanged` event without actually changing the `Text`, the `Updated` and `Refresh` Methods deal mainly with refreshing the drawing of the Control. But if this is something that you need to add to additional TextBoxes you can try making an `Extension method`, or you can add a Handler to your TextBox's Invalidated Event .

**Using the Invalidated event**

```
void textBox1_Invalidated(object sender, InvalidateEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1_TextChanged(sender, new EventArgs());
}
```

**Extension Method**

I will admit that this is probably overkill....

Quick and dirty example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ExtensionMethods;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.RefreshCurrent();
        }
    }
}

namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static void RefreshCurrent( this TextBox tb)
        {
            string temp = tb.Text;
            tb.Text = "";
            tb.Text = temp;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much you've understanded what I need, sorry 'cause my english.

Comment: `EventArgs.Empty` is available instead of `New EventArgs()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try inserting `Me.Refresh()` like so

```
Private Sub Refresh_Textbox_Text(ByVal TextBox As TextBox)

   Dim TempText As String = TextBox.Text
    TextBox.Clear()
    TextBox.Text = TempText
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to add anything to the snippet I've posted... I think you don't understanded it, my snippet is working, the problem is I ask if I can reproduce the same with a native method because if I use "Textbox1.Refresh" or "Textbox1.invalidate" the "TextChanged" event does not succed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the 4th step completely, but have a look to the following code

```
Dim ListItems1 As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Label1.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListItems1.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    ListView1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    Label1.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text.Length = 0 Then
        Button1.Enabled = False
    Else
        If ListItems1.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
            Label1.Text = "Directory is already in the listview"
            Button1.Enabled = False
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Directory is not in the listview"
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

if you don't want a button to exist, try the following

```
Dim ListItems1 As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text.Length = 0 Then
        Label1.Text = ""
    Else
        If ListItems1.Contains(TextBox1.Text) Then
            Label1.Text = "Directory is already in the listview"
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Directory is not in the listview"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 And ListItems1.Contains(TextBox1.Text) = False And TextBox1.Text.Length > 0 Then
        ListItems1.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        ListView1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        Label1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```